# Producing multiple maximum and minimum values with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2007

I'm becoming frustrated with a curious limitation of SQL - its apparent inability to relate one record to another outside of aggregate functions. My problem is summarized thusly.
I have a table, already sorted. I need to find its maximum values (note the plural!) and minimum values. No, I am not looking for a single maximum or single minimum. More specifically I'm trying to generate a list of the local peaks of a numeric sequence. A rough description of an algorithm to generate this is:

```
WHILE NOT END_OF_TABLE
 IF RECORD != FIRST_RECORD AND RECORD != LAST_RECORD THEN
  IF ((RECORD(Field)<RECORD_PREVIOUS(Field) AND RECORD(Field)<RECORD_NEXT(Field)) OR
      RECORD(Field)>RECORD_PREVIOUS(Field) AND RECORD(Field)>RECORD_NEXT(Field)) THEN
     ADD_RESULT RECORD
  END IF
 END IF
END WHILE
```

See the Problem? I need to do a query that a given record must compare against the previous and next records' values. Can this even be accomplished in standard SQL?

Comment: How is the table sorted?  Does it have a primary key?

Comment: Sample data probably helps, with table schema too...

Comment: @Andomar It's sorted on the independent variable. :) This represents the outputs of a mathematical function f(x)=y. x is what it is sorted on. It has a primary key of "id". But the data is entered already sorted.

Comment: @Martin I'm currently using Microsoft Access 2007 but I might migrate to a current version of MySQL. The ideal solution would be generic enough for both.

Comment: @gbn I'm not sure what would be an appropriate sample set for this. The table is quite large. I'm doing numeric analysis of an unknown function only having the dependent and independent terms. f(x)=y
There is a key, but it can be any unique identifier. Assume it's random valued. :) There is the 'x' and 'y' fields and the DB is sorted on the 'x' field (ascending). 'x' & 'y' are both floating point values of any precision.

Comment: @Richard Robertson: SQL databases don't remember the order in which you insert rows.  There are keys and indexes which can be sorted, but there is no inherent "row order".  That is why SQL has no easy way to compare previous and next rows.

Answer (score 2):

Your frustration is shared by many; while SQL is great for working with *general* sets, it's terribly deficient when trying to work with issues specific to *ordered* sets (whether it's physically ordered in the table or there is an implicit or explicit logical order is irrelevant). There are some things that can help (for example, the `rank()` and `row_number()` functions), but the solutions can differ across RDBMS's.

If you can be specific about which platform you're working with, I or someone else can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: I think that the full ANSI `OVER` clause would probably allow this sort of thing so its not a limitation of SQL per se. but SQL Server hasn't implemented it fully.

Comment: `over` is available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @antisanity. The keyword was "full". There are a load of suggestions on the connect site [by Itzik Ben Gan](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?UserHandle=Itzik+Ben-Gan) to extend it further.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not aware of how SQL Server's implementation of windowing functions (in 2008 and beyond) is incomplete; is there something you're aware of that's missing?

Comment: @Adam - It's covered well in this paper by Itzik here http://www.insidetsql.com/OVER_Clause_and_Ordered_Calculations.doc I'm not absolutely certain if these suggestions would meeet the OP's requirements but they are in the same kind of direction.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the link! I have a feeling that some of thing features that *are* available (like `row_number()`) would be sufficient (assuming the OP's using SQL Server; he still hasn't specified a specific RDBMS), though that paper does point out some interesting possibilities that would, if nothing else, give us the opportunity to both simplify and clarify existing queries on ordered sets.

Comment: @Adam My point exactly. Thanks for your reply. My immediate choice is Microsoft Access 2007, but MySQL is available as well. An ideal solution would work for both.

Answer (score 2):

You have to self-join twice and generate a rownumber without gaps:

In T-SQL:

```
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY your_sort_order) AS RowNumber
           ,* -- other columns here
)
SELECT *
FROM ordered
LEFT JOIN ordered AS prev
    ON prev.RowNumber = ordered.RowNumber - 1
LEFT JOIN ordered AS next
    ON next.RowNumber = ordered.RowNumber + 1
WHERE -- here you put in your local min/local max and end-point handling logic - end points will have NULL in next/prev
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Could you explain how it works in more detail for future reference? And is it compatible with Microsoft Access 2007 and MySQL?

Comment: The technique works in anything - Access does not support the WITH construct to make the Common Table Expression, not sure about MySQL.  ROW_NUMBER() may not be supported in either.  You're basically converting the set into an ordered set and assiging a number based on the order.  Then simply joining to itself twice to get predecessor and successor rows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need a self join - but without a database schema, it's hard to be specific about the solution.

Specifically, I'm wondering about the "ordering" thing you mention - but I'm going to assume there's an "ID" field we can use for this.

(Oh, and I'm using old-school join syntax, coz I'm a dinosaur).

```
select *
from   myTable   main,
       myTable   previous,
       myTable   next
where  previous.id  = main.id - 1
and    next.id      = main.id + 1
and    previous.record > main.record
and    next.record     < main.record
```

(I think I've interpreted your requirement correctly in the greater/less than clauses, but adjust to taste).

Comment: This will only work if there's a clear way to determine *what* the ID of the next and previous records are (in your case, they're contiguous). This won't work if there are gaps.

Comment: yep - in the absence of a schema, I made some assumptions. If there are gaps, you can replace the "+1" and "-1" with a subquery to find the greatest / lowest value for ID smaller than the current one.

Comment: The last two conditions of the WHERE clause need correction.  Maxima = (Main > Previous AND Main > Next), Minima = (Main < Previous AND Main < Next)

Comment: Hmm. I thought I had tagged this for Microsoft Access, but it might also be done in MySQL. Access is more readily available at the moment. And the table can be considered to be 3 fields, int ID, X value, and Y value. The Y value field is the one in consideration. The table will have already been sorted ascending on the X value field. That help. The x value isn't necessarily a integer or it could substitute for the Index :)

Comment: @adam Yep. The id field does exist, and is likely to be contiguous, but there is chance of it not being sequential.

Comment: @Neville Good specific solution even it only produces 1/2 of the possible results :p Actually, if it wasn't for the issue that @Adam pointed out, I'd just have to create an additional version for the second half and merge them together. Ever studied calculus? I'm trying to locate local extremas in a function.

Comment: @Neville Good assumptions. Schema: random ID for the key (int), sorted on field 'X' (float), the field being compared against is 'y' (float). The 'x' field should be regard instead of id for sort order. How would you implement that subquery for x?

Comment: @Dems You're correct about @Neville's omission. How would you re-word the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  current.RowID,
  current.Value,
  CASE WHEN
    (
     (current.Value < COALESCE(previous.Value,   current.Value + 1))
     AND
     (current.Value < COALESCE(subsequent.Value, current.Value + 1))
    )
  THEN
    'Minima'
  ELSE
    'Maxima'
  END
FROM
  myTable  current
LEFT JOIN
  myTable  previous
    ON previous.RowID = (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM myTable WHERE RowID < current.ROWID)
LEFT JOIN
  myTable  subsequent
    ON subsequent.RowID = (SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM myTable WHERE RowID > current.ROWID)
WHERE
  (
   (current.Value < COALESCE(previous.Value,   current.Value + 1))
   AND
   (current.Value < COALESCE(subsequent.Value, current.Value + 1))
  )
  OR
  (
   (current.Value > COALESCE(previous.Value,   current.Value - 1))
   AND
   (current.Value > COALESCE(subsequent.Value, current.Value - 1))
  )
```

**Note:** The < and > logic is copied from you, but does not cater for local maxima/minima that are equal across one or more consecutive records.

**Note:** I've created a fictional RowID to join the records in order, all the is important is that the joins get the "previous" and "subsequent" records.

**Note:** The LEFT JOINs and COALESCE statements cause the first and last values to always be counted as a maxima or minima.

Comment: Can't assume that the ordering value is an integer unfortunately. In this case it's a float. For instance a sequence that I'm currently using begins (x only):0,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5...,239.5,240
Notice the end values are not the same step as the others? This is a real-world data set; no help for it. :(
Also can this solution work in Microsoft Access 2007 and MySQL?
And, yes, I considered the issue of (Value = Previous AND Value = Subsequent). Those represent points of inflection rather than extrema. Separate handling required.

Comment: If you don't have a mechanism to algebraically derive the "next" and "previous" ordering values, you have two options: Create one (physically, such as an Identity Column, or virtually, such as the mentioned use of ROW_NUMBER() in other answers), or to use correlated sub-queries.  I have updated the answer with a correlated sub-query.